# KafkaConsumer with Multithreading

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Created below KafkaConsumer, that will take topicName, partitionNo, beginOffset and endOffset as parameters. But below logic I can execute for one partition at a time because KafkaConsumer is not thread safe. If I want to complete the all 20 partitions it is taking longer time. So how to implement the KafkaConsumer with multi threads so that I can search all partitions at the same time ?

"I have a topic with 20 partitions and has employee data. From UI search screen, I will pass employee number and birth Date, Now I want to search all these 20 partitions to find a particular employees data is there are not. If it is matches then I want put in a separate List and download as file."

```
   public List<String> searchMessages(String topicName, int partitionNo, long beginOffset, long endOffset) {

List<String> filteredMessages = new ArrayList<>();
TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topicName", partitionNo);
Properties clusterOneProps = kafkaConsumerConfig.getConsumerProperties();
KafkaConsumer<String, Object> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(clusterOneProps);

try {
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topicName"), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        consumer.seek(tp, beginOffset); 
    }
}); 
Thread.sleep(100);    
boolean flag = true;
System.out.println("search started......from offset is "+beginOffset);
while(flag) {   
ConsumerRecords<String, Object> crs = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100L));
 for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : crs) {
          // search criteria
           if(record.value().toString().contains("01111") && record.value().toString().contains("2021-11-06")) {
               System.out.println("founddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd "+record.offset());
               filteredMessages.add(record.value().toString());
           }
           if (record.offset() == endOffset) {
               flag = false;
               break;
           }
    }
 }
 System.out.println("doneeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    consumer.close();
}
```

Comment: Why not use Kafka Streams DSL filter function with `num.threads=20`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Kafka Parallel Consumer library. Check the library [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer), and this [blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-confluent-parallel-message-processing-client/).

It's possible to 'simulate' parallel consumption with the normal consumar (by having multiple consumers), but you have to hand roll a good amount of code. [This blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-consumer-multi-threaded-messaging/) explains this approach, but I recommend using the parallel consumer.

Comment: Thanks @Augusto.. I will try this. Can I pass beginOffset to ParallelConsumer to seek from particular offset ? I know  beginOffset for each partition in advance, so I want ParallelConsumer start processing messages from each partition from that particular offset.  I have retention policy as 3 days on each topic.

Comment: That's a good question and I'm not sure unfortunately. You could update the committed offsets of the consumer group before starting the parallel consumer using [AdminClient.alterConsumerGroupOffsets()](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#alterConsumerGroupOffsets(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)). This would yield the same result. A word of caution, changing committed offsets is a tricky thing if you have multiple instances of the applications. You would need to stop consuming from all apps before updating the offsets and then start the consumers again.